# Display latest image from directory

Tags: php

I use this to display the latest image from 2 directories where images from cameras upload every 10s
The code works, but as I know I might end up with potentially 10s of thousands of images in each directory I believe the code is not optimized for the situation.
Also I reload the whole page every 10s where maybe it would be more efficient to just update the images.
Could someone help giving me directions to optimize this?
Thanks a lot.

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "10";
    $base_url_east = 'East/snap/';
    $base_url_south = 'South/snap/';
    $newest_mtime_east = 0;
    $show_file_east = 'BROKEN';
    if ($handle = opendir($base_url_east)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != '.htaccess')) {
                $mtime = filemtime("$base_url_east/$file");
                if ($mtime > $newest_mtime_east) {
                    $newest_mtime_east = $mtime;
                    $show_file_east = "$base_url_east/$file";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $newest_mtime_south = 0;
    $show_file_south = 'BROKEN';
    if ($handle = opendir($base_url_south)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != '.htaccess')) {
                $mtime = filemtime("$base_url_south/$file");
                if ($mtime > $newest_mtime_south) {
                    $newest_mtime_south = $mtime;
                    $show_file_south = "$base_url_south/$file";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
        <center>
        <?php
            print '<img src="' .$show_file_east. '" alt="Latest image uploaded" width="720" height="480">';
            print '<img src="' .$show_file_south. '" alt="Latest image uploaded" width="720" height="480">';
        ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How get the directories populated with files? Some script doing this? Or just manually?

Comment: Get rid of `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` and use AJAX to append the DOM with new images.

Comment: When you upload a new image just save its file name to a database to retrieve its file name rather then iterating through all files and get the latest one.

Comment: Upload via ftp auto by the cameras.

Comment: I will investigate Ajax DOM way to get new images... Don't know yet how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If the new files are named **East/snap/current.jpg** and **South/snap/current.jpg**, you could easily use the HTML even without PHP like this

```
<img src="East/snap/current.jpg" alt="Latest image uploaded" width="720" height="480">
<img src="South/snap/current.jpg" alt="Latest image uploaded" width="720" height="480">
```

The one/script uploads the photos should be responsible for

- copying the already uploaded **current.jpg** to **2016-08-13-07:00:00.jpg** (or some other filename containing eg. the date
- copying the new file to **current.jpg**

**EDIT**

If you cannot modify the filenames like I said above, try

```
$string = date('Ymd-H'); // 20160812-12
$files = glob('Schedule_' . $string . '*.jpg');
```

This will get you all files into an array, which were taken in the current hour. It could be that you get a problem, if the script is called 9 seconds, after the hour changed, because it won't find an image from that hour. But with this way you can minimize the count of scanned files.

**EDIT**

This script is not tested, but should return one recent file for one folder:

```
<?php

$basePath = '/home/user/camera/East/snap';

// Scans files from the current and the last minutes
// this ensures that always files will be found, even if the minute changed
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver'));

$prefixCurrentMinute = $basePath . '/Schedule_' . $date->format('Ymd-Hi') . '*.jpg';
$date->sub(new \DateInterval('PT1M'));
$prefixLastMinute = $basePath . '/Schedule_' . $date->format('Ymd-Hi') . '*.jpg';

$files = array_merge(
    glob($prefixLastMinute),
    glob($prefixCurrentMinute)
);

$lastFile = 'dummy.jpg';

if (is_array($files) AND count($files) > 0) {
    // this methods sorts the files "regularly" by default, and I guess
    // regularly means alpha-numeric in ascending order ...
    sort($files);

    $lastFile = $files[0];
    // use this, if the order is not ascending after using sort() on the array
    // $lastFile = $files[count($files) - 1];
}

$eastPhoto = basename($lastFile);
?>

<img src="East/snap/<?php echo $eastPhoto; ?>" alt="Latest image uploaded" width="720" height="480">
```

Comment: The cameras upload via ftp  to the directories. I have no way to change file names by the cameras at the upload time. File names are in the format: Schedule_20160812-123433.jpg

Comment: Would that be more efficient to glob the directory for jpg, sort the array, and get the last to display, instead of iterating for mod date?

Comment: Thank you Edgar I will try this now. About the hour problem, if this happens, then what happens really? An error or just ignore?

Comment: Your two lines build the array of current hour images. I have to grab last in the array, not sure how to do this. A potential other issue is server time. Server is in Europe but cameras in Vancouver BC with local time.